# ARRAYSIZE C++ macro: how does it work?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

OK, I'm not *entirely* a newbie, but I cannot say I understand the following macro. The most confusing part is the division with value cast to size_t: what on earth does that accomplish? Especially, since I see a negation operator, which, as far as I know, might result in a zero value. Does not this mean that it can lead to a division-by-zero error?  (By the way, the macro *is* correct and works beautifully.)

```
#define ARRAYSIZE(a) \
  ((sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a))) / \
  static_cast<size_t>(!(sizeof(a) % sizeof(*(a)))))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first part `(sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a)))` is fairly straightforward; it's dividing the size of the entire array (assuming you pass the macro an object of array type, and not a pointer), by the size of the first element.  This gives the number of elements in the array.

The second part is not so straightforward.  I think the potential division-by-zero is intentional; it will lead to a compile-time error if, for whatever reason, the size of the array is not an integer multiple of one of its elements.  In other words, it's some kind of compile-time sanity check.

However, I can't see under what circumstances this could occur...  As people have suggested in comments below, it will catch *some* misuse (like using `ARRAYSIZE()` on a pointer).  It won't catch all errors like this, though.

Comment: I think it's there to catch an occasional misuse of the macro, like calling it on a pointer rather than an array. Unfortunately, it doesn't catch things like calling it on a pointer to an object that's the same size as the pointer.

Comment: The main circumstance I can think of is when `a` is a pointer, to something whose size isn't a factor of `sizeof (a)`. So most classes, you'd expect, but you won't get the desired division-by-zero if `a` is a `char*`. There are better ways to write an ARRAYSIZE helper in C++ so as to get a warning/error when it's used with a pointer. And this is C++ only, not dual-use C++ and C, because of the `static_cast`.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote this version of this macro.  Consider the older version:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a)))

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct stat stats[32];
  std::cout << "sizeof stats = " << (sizeof stats) << "\n";
  std::cout << "sizeof *stats = " << (sizeof *stats) << "\n";
  std::cout << "ARRAYSIZE=" << ARRAYSIZE(stats) << "\n";

  foo(stats);
}

void foo(struct stat stats[32]) {
  std::cout << "sizeof stats = " << (sizeof stats) << "\n";
  std::cout << "sizeof *stats = " << (sizeof *stats) << "\n";
  std::cout << "ARRAYSIZE=" << ARRAYSIZE(stats) << "\n";
}
```

On a 64-bit machine, this code produces this output:

```
sizeof stats = 4608
sizeof *stats = 144
ARRAYSIZE=32
sizeof stats = 8
sizeof *stats = 144
ARRAYSIZE=0
```

What's going on?  How did the ARRAYSIZE go from 32 to zero?  Well, the problem is the function parameter is actually a pointer, even though it looks like an array.  So inside of foo, "sizeof(stats)" is 8 bytes, and "sizeof(*stats)" is still 144.

With the new macro:

```
#define ARRAYSIZE(a) \
  ((sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a))) / \
  static_cast<size_t>(!(sizeof(a) % sizeof(*(a)))))
```

When sizeof(a) is not a multiple of sizeof(* (a)), the % is not zero, which the ! inverts, and then the static_cast evaluates to zero, causing a compile-time division by zero.  So to the extent possible in a macro, this weird division catches the problem at compile-time.

PS: in C++17, just use std::size, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Comment: std::size(a) ! Best suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

The division at the end seems to be an *attempt* at detecting a non-array argument (e.g. pointer).

It fails to detect that for, for example, `char*`, but would work for `T*` where `sizeof(T)` is greater than the size of a pointer.

In C++, one usually prefers the following function template:

```
typedef ptrdiff_t Size;

template< class Type, Size n >
Size countOf( Type (&)[n] ) { return n; }
```

This function template can't be instantiated with pointer argument, only array. In C++11 it can alternatively be expressed in terms of `std::begin` and `std::end`, which automagically lets it work also for standard containers with random access iterators.

Limitations: doesn't work for array of local type in C++03, and doesn't yield compile time size.

For compile time size you can instead do like

```
template< Size n > struct Sizer { char elems[n]; };

template< class Type, size n >
Sizer<n> countOf_( Type (&)[n] );

#define COUNT_OF( a ) sizeof( countOf_( a ).elems )
```

Disclaimer: all code untouched by compiler's hands.

But in general, just use the first function template, `countOf`.

Cheers & hth.

Answer (score 3):

suppose we have

```
T arr[42];
```

`ARRAYSIZE(arr)` will expand to (rougly)

```
sizeof (arr) / sizeof(*arr) / !(sizeof(arr) % sizeof(*arr))
```

which in this case gives 42/!0 which is 42

If for some reason sizeof array is not divisible by sizeof its element, division by zero will occur. When can it happen? For example when you pass a dynamically allocated array instead of a static one!

Answer (score 2):

It does lead to a division-by-zero error (intentionally). The way that this macro works is it divides the size of the array in bytes by the size of a single array element in bytes. So if you have an array of `int` values, where an `int` is 4 bytes (on most 32-bit machines), an array of 4 `int` values would be 16 bytes.

So when you call this macro on such an array, it does `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)`. And since 16 / 4 = 4, it returns that there are 4 elements in the array.

Note: `*array` dereferences the first element of the array and is equivalent to `array[0]`.

The second division does modulo-division (gets the remainder of the division), and since any non-zero value is considered "true", using the `!` operator would cause a division by zero if the remainder of the division is non-zero (and similarly, division by 1 otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

The div-by-zero may be trying to catch alignment errors caused by whatever reason. Like if, with some compiler settings, the size of an array element were 3 but the compiler would round it to 4 for faster array access, then an array of 4 entries would have the size of 16 and !(16/3) would go to zero, giving division-by-zero at compile time. Yet, I don't know of any compiler doing like that, and it may be against the specification of C++ for sizeof to return a size that differs from the size of that type in an array..

Answer (score -2):

Coming late to the party here...

Google's C++ codebase has IMHO *the* definitive C++ implementation of the `arraysize()` macro, which includes several wrinkles that aren't considered here.

I cannot improve upon [the source](http://web.archive.org/web/20150904013642/http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/third_party/cld/base/macros.h), which has clear and complete comments.

Comment: The link is dead now, leaving this answer devoid of any information.

Comment: The dead link should be fixed now.