# How do I modify the character array in this struct ~> C

Tags: c

Okay, I have a struct

```
typedef struct contact {

    char firstName[32];
    char lastName[32];
    char address[100];
    char city[32];
    char state[32];
    char zipcode[10];

} Contact;
```

And I need to make the value of firstName equal to "Herp"
I've tried something like this:

```
int main(void) { 
    Contact contact;
    contact.firstName = "Herp"; // I also tried the following line of code:
    contact.firstName[] = "Herp"; // This doesn't work, and when I add a 0 to where the array needs to point, I get a syntax error.
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the return statement in main. This can be ignored for now as it is an example code.

Comment: try `strcpy(contact.firstName,"Herp");`

Comment: @BinayakaChakraborty right direction, but unsafe implementation...

Comment: @Alnitak: it all depends on the context... that line is, for example, completely safe.

Comment: @Alnitak: yeah, best bet would be `strncpy()` :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath in this _specific_ code it's safe, but as soon as the OP tries to use this code with user supplied data it'll have the potential to fail badly...

Comment: @Alnitak: that's what I said, it all depends on the *context*. for example, just because you use `strncpy`, it doesn't mean it's *safe*. for example, if you just silently truncate the string, that could have worse effects than a potential crash in some context (eg: banking).

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  Its a basic, but perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structure will put aside 32 bytes of memory for `.firstName` for each instance, and likewise for the other `char[]` fields.

The `char[32]` buffer can be read as if it's a `char*` pointer variable, but if you write `contact.firstName = "Herp"` it's as if you were trying to reassign the field's memory address.  However you can't do that - the address of that buffer is fixed relative to the start of the entire structure in memory.

Hence you have to *copy* the desired data from the original string into the buffer.

In limited circumstances you can use `strcpy` for this, but ideally you should use `strncpy` instead to ensure that you cannot overflow from one field into another.

Do beware of the possibility of the resulting buffer not having a terminating `NUL` in it if the original string was 32+ characters long.

Comment: Again, now what I've been trying to do is clear to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I voted up noelicus' answer, but I feel it needs to go a little further.

```
typedef struct contact {

    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
    char* address;
    char* city;
    char* state;
    char* zipcode;

} Contact;
```

Then this will work:

```
contact.firstName = "Herp";
```

The reason is that the pointer will be set to point to the allocated space that contains the string.

In your case the String has already been allocated and you need to copy the constant string over (C strings are immutable). I would say that the better way to do this is:

```
strncpy(contact.firstName, "Herp", sizeof(contact.firstName));
```

This form will protect against a possible stack overflow. You will never be able to copy more bytes to the target string than it can hold.

Comment: one should also point out that if your structure contains pointers rather than char arrays it'll be a lot harder to deallocate - especially if some of those pointers refer to string constants rather than dynamically allocated memory and you've no record of which were which!  It would be safer to use `strdup` consistently than copy pointers to string constants.

Answer (score 2):

```
strcpy(contact.firstName,"Herp");
```

You need to *copy* the string into the array of characters (string).

Using square brackets will access a character within the string, e.g. `contact.firstName[0]` to access the first character.

**Edit:**
`strcpy` is a good place to start and learn strings, but in a real system is not safe as it will not check there is room in the buffer you're copying into. If you want to read more on safe string handling try [strcpy_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) etc - to be safe the functions need to be given the maximum array/string size, for example by using the [ARRAYSIZE macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064134/arraysize-c-macro-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Wow, thank you. Also, just wondering why is my question downvoted so much, as when I searched the website, there was nothing I found that helped me for what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user2832888 I'm not among the downvoters, but I believe the question was downvoted because StackOverflow is not a substitute for a beginner's book on C. Questions such as this get asked many many times (I've seen almost exactly the same question several times in the last *week*) and take screen space among other questions without providing a tangible benefit to future users.

Comment: I wish this answer mentioned the security issues associated with just strcpy'ing arbitrary strings into a 32 byte fixed array.

Comment: @SirDarius like mine does, you mean? ;-)

Comment: Have added a bit about it. I didn't originally since it was clearly a beginner question and the very concept of strings needed to be understood - but I take your point it's a good place to mention it, but we mustn't put people off with the deep end!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid buffer-overflow

```
strncpy(contact.firstName,"Herp",32);
```

Ensure that the value you pass as "Herp" can't be more than 31 characters, as explained by Alnitak :)

Comment: Using a constant should be done with a define "#define FIRST_NAME_LEN 32". That way you change it in one spot and it updates everywhere. If you use the numeric constant, you need to update it everywhere. If you miss one, you've got a bug.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek: That was just a quick small code fragment, but yeah that is obvious :) Thanks for the remainder!